# Loading js modules dynamically and provide instant access to the functions inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I want to create a module loader for javascript files using $.getScript but since the loading of the scripts is then asynchronously when I put a function call of a module inside the document they may be called before the module was loaded. Is there any way to avoid this situation maybe by putting the function call on hold until the module was loaded successfully?

framework.core.js:

```
var Framework = $.extend(Framework, Framework.Core = { 
    modules: [ 
        'Module1', 
        'Module2'
    ], 
    init: function () { 
        $.each(modules, function (index, value) {  
            $.getScript('framework.' + value.toLowerCase() + '.js', function () { 
            }); 
        }); 
    }   

}); 
Framework.Core.init();
```

site.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="framework.core.js"></script>
        <script>Framework.Module1.functionCall();</script>  // Call a function independent of the completion of the framework.core.js loader
    </head>
...
```

Comment: Let the function wait for the module and DOMready, but don't let ready wait for the script.

Comment: The problem is that I want to provide the functionality of the modules loaded independent of the DOM ready event. In case I have some script tags inside my document body calling functions in the module they should be executed as soon as the module was loaded.

Comment: Yes, just hook them on the load callback of the module script.

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: Maybe [`$.ajax("myModule.js", {cache:true, dataType:"script"}).then(myFunctionThatNeedsTheModule);`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

Comment: I've added some sample code to show what I want to be able to do

Comment: try $.getScript(src,callback(data,status,xhr){
  //do something with data
})

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the success callback for the depending functions to hook on it. You will not be able to defer the execution of those following functions to wait for the Module (unless you would insert the script via `document.write`), so the callback is necessary. Best, just make the `Deferred` object (returned by the ajax function) public. Also, you should not use [`jQuery.getScript/`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for that task at all, because it prevents caching.

```
var Framework = $.extend(Framework, Framework.Core = {
// The "Core" property seems pretty useless, by the way ^^
    modules: [ 
        'Module1', 
        'Module2'
    ],
    loads: {},
    init: function () { 
        $.each(this.modules, function(index, value) {  
            this.loads[value] = $.ajax({
                url: 'framework.' + value.toLowerCase() + '.js',
                cache:true,
                dataType:"script"
            }); 
        }); 
    }   

}); 
Framework.init();
```

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="framework.core.js"></script>
        <script>Framework.loads.Module1.then(function() {
            functionCall();
        }); // Call a function as soon as the module is loaded
        </script>
    </head>
...
```